# Best way to make elements non-selectable in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, canvas, stage

All,

As part of requirements for a new feature of "locking" a page, it is desired to have all elements on a locked page be non-selectable.  This is not to be confused with disabled.  All elements should appear as if the page were active, but not be selectable.

The current thought is to create a clear canvas and place it over the existing elements.  With this thought, I have two questions:

1. if you can think of a better way to make all items non-selectable than applying a clear canvas element over the existing elements could you describe it?
2. if not, what is the best way to retrofit existing implementations to accept the overlayed canvas item?  BTW, all .mxml pages inherit from a custom .as file.

Sorry if this is not very descriptive, however, I am new to Flex and have spent many days trying to figure this out.

Thanks,
Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All,

To fully "lock" a screen from user manipulation, one must combine Chris Bos's and www.Flextras.com's answers:  disable mouse input (mouseChildren) and disable keyboard focus (focusEnabled).

Todd

Answer (score 4):

You could also set the mouseChildren property of the page to false so the elements will not receive any mouseEvents

Comment: +1. I didn't know about that property before. Learn something new every day. :)

Comment: I like this idea a lot.  It is a lot less intrusive than my original concept.  Thanks!  I will work on it.

Answer (score 1):

Would the [focusEnabled](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#focusEnabled) property work for you?

Documentation says it only relates to "Tabbing", but my memory says it relates to all sorts of selection.

Comment: I will look into this as it may need to be combined with the other suggestion for full locking.  Thanks for the tip.  Sorry, but only one answer can be selected.

Comment: @Todd If neither my answer, nor the other answer, is complete; you should post your own answer with the actual solution and mark that as such.  If I helped, feel free to show some love by upvoting me.

Comment: @Flextras thanks, that was/is my intention, however, yesterday didn't allow me to get to test the answers given to see if a combination was indeed necessary.  I am testing now.

Comment: @Todd thanks for the karma points.  Be sure to accept your own answer as the correct one.